# Write output of replaceStream to new file

Tags: node.js, npm

I am writing a progrma in node and using [replaceStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replacestream) and I want to write the out of replacestream to a file, but all I can get it to do write now is print to the console using this code:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath + "/" + fileName)
.pipe(replaceStream(imagePath, newPath))
.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write it to a [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath + "/" + fileName)
    .pipe(replaceStream(imagePath, newPath))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath + "/" + newFileName));
```